# Why doesn't Java standard libraries implement toString methods?

Tags: java

`Object.toString()` JavaDoc says:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the *toString* method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

Still, so many of the standard java classes like `Collections` (Sets, Lists etc) that could have a very useful `toString()` methods, don't bother implementing it. Is there a reason for this stupidity?

Or hey, would you like a hex string instead? :)

EDIT: Oops, this was my failure in using my IDE. I followed the interface instead of the implementation and that took me for some reason straight to `Object.toString()`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2329168/334274

Comment: Which collection classes don't implement toString? I think that all of them implement it (ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet)

Comment: Collections is a util class so I do not any good reason for toString method. If you mean Collection interface in that case in Java all functions are virtual so the toString from implementation is called which is in most cases overrided.

Comment: java.util.Collections is not instantiable, why do you need an overriden toString() for it?

Comment: Collections is a utility class. how would having a toString method be useful?

Answer (score 6):

**UPD:**

If you mean `Collection` classes, so answer will be:
this is not exactly like this. Many of the `Collection` classes override this method; for example, the `AbstractCollection` class,  which has its own `toString` implementation - common for all inherited classes.

If you mean `Collection[s]`, then this class has a private constructor and can not be instantiated; so a special `toString` method is pointless.

Comment: he mentioned Collections which a util class not Collection which is an interface.

Comment: @gregory561, I'm afraid, that author made a misprint.

Comment: in that case a question does not make any sense as the Collection interface does not extends/implement Object? which has toString method. Even if it did it is impossible to implement this method in an iterface

Answer (score 2):

If You are talking about [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class, it is utility class, it is not necessary to have toString() method overridden. Generally in case of utility classes we make constructors private and provide static methods.

Also check you can not create an object of Collections class becuase it's constructor is made private. Check `java.util.Collections` [source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java.util/Collections.java.html), Line number 56